# Repeat function only 3 times then change Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Ok so, I made this Rock, Paper, Scissors game with Tkinter for school and it runs properly but I wanted to add a possibility where the game only runs three times. You know like when you are with a friend and you only play best out of three. Add so I created a function called ThreeRun that runs the main window and it's supposed to give the final outcome after variable RepCall==3. That variable is global and is connected to the functions Pretender that is activated every time the player plays (with the button called go).

Well, that did definitely not work out as planned and now I've run out of ideas.
Here's the code. I acknowledge the fact that it is a miserable mess but that's as much as I could do. By the way, that is only the important part of the program.

```
def ThreeRun():
    global labord,labtoi,radlst,kill,ans,go,tl,var
    global ptoi, pord, RepCall
    UltimWindow()
    if RepCall==3:
        if ptoi==pord:
            showinfo(title="Conclusion",message=m1)
            LeHide(erlst2)
            MainDow()
        elif ptoi>pord:
            showinfo(title="Conclusion",message=m2)
            LeHide(erlst2)
            MainDow()
        elif ptoi<pord:
            showinfo(title="Conclusion",message=m3)
            LeHide(erlst2)
            MainDow()
    pass

def UltimWindow():
    global labord,labtoi,radlst,kill,ans,go,tl,var,imlst
    erlst1=[imglab,normlab,mod1,mod2,Quit]
    LeHide(erlst1)

    root.geometry("690x465")
    root.configure(bg='#eead0e')
    
    var=IntVar()
    
    piedra = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Prog\Projects\SpongeRock.png")
    papel = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Prog\Projects\SpongePaper.png")
    tijeras = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Prog\Projects\SpongeTijeras.png")
    karen = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Prog\Projects\SpongeKaren.png")
    calamar = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\User\Documents\School\Prog\Projects\SpongeCalamar.png")

    imlst=[(0),("Roche",piedra,1),("Papier",papel,2),("Ciseaux",tijeras,3)]

    def ShowChoice():
        labtoi.configure(image=imlst[var.get()][1])
        pass
    
    def Pretender():
        global ptoi,pord,ans,RepCall,var,imlst
        RepCall+=1
        jou=var.get() 
        if jou==0:
           errbox=showerror(title="Aucun choisi!",message="Choisis entre Roche, Papier ou Ciseaux!")
        else:
            ordi=randint(1,3)
            labord.configure(image=imlst[ordi][1])
            ans.configure(bg='#5b1ab0',fg="White",font=('Tw Cen MT',10),height=3,width=20)
            if ordi == jou:
                ans.configure(text=str(imlst[ordi][0])+" annule "+str(imlst[jou][0])+"\nPoints du 
                joueur:"+str(ptoi)+"\nPoints de l' Ordi:"+str(pord))
            elif (ordi==1 and jou==3) or (ordi==2 and jou==1) or (ordi==3 and jou==2):
                pord+=1
                ans.configure(text=str(imlst[ordi][0])+" bat "+str(imlst[jou][0])+"\nPoints du 
                joueur:"+str(ptoi)+"\nPoints de l' Ordi:"+str(pord))
            else:
                ptoi+=1
                ans.configure(text=str(imlst[jou][0])+" bat "+str(imlst[ordi][0])+"\nPoints du 
                joueur:"+str(ptoi)+"\nPoints de l' Ordi:"+str(pord))       
            pass

    tl=Label(root, text = "Roche, Papier, Ciseaux!",bg='#3aaaaa',font=('Magneto',15))
    tl.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=50,pady=(15))
    labord= Label(root,text="Choix de l'Ordi", image = karen,bg='black',fg='white',font=('Tw Cen 
    MT',10),compound=TOP)
    labord.karen=karen
    labord.grid(row=2,column=2)
    labtoi= Label(root,text="Choix du Joueur", image = calamar,bg='black',fg='white',font=('Tw Cen 
    MT',10),compound=TOP)
    labtoi.calamar=calamar
    labtoi.grid(row=2,column=0)
    ans=Label(root,bg='#eead0e',height=3,width=20)
    ans.grid(row=3,column=1)

    for choix, img, val in imlst[1:]:
        rad=tk.Radiobutton(root,
                           text=choix,image=img,
                           font=('Tw Cen MT',10),bg='black',
                           fg='white',compound=TOP,
                           indicatoron = 0,
                           variable=var, 
                           command=ShowChoice,
                           value=val)
        rad.grid(row=1,column=val-1,padx=10,pady=(15,30))
        radlst.append(rad)

    go=Button(root, text="VS",bg='firebrick',fg='White',font=('Impact',30),width=5,command=Pretender)
    go.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=(15,30))
    kill=Button(root, text="Quiter",bg='#3aaaaa',font=('Magneto',10),command=FinDestination)
    kill.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=10,pady=15)
    pass

run1=MainDow()
pass
```

runmain=GWindow()

Comment: I think this question is too specific. You should come up with a more general question and a much simpler code sample. Try to abstract from your specific project and rather ask (yourself also) what do you want to achieve, in a general sense. Moreover, the code you are providing uses functions and variables that are not defined, it is unreadable in my opinion.

Comment: I did not add the other functions since they are not relevant to the question. You are right, it is a specific question but I could not solve it on my own, and believe me, I've tried. That's why it's here. Thank's anyway.

Comment: In some sense, none of the code provided is relevant here, as it is unreadable in its current state. You should provided a much simpler version of it if you want people to read it. For instance, the fact that you are doing a Rock paper scissors game is irrelevant also and you could remove everything that is related to the game logic.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

`turns = []`

`def ThreeRun():`

```
global turns
turns.append(0)

if len(turns) == 3:
   return 'Game Over'
```

Every time this function is called it will check whether 3 turns have passed, if not it will continue.

Just modify it in your way for the game